# Why does console.log("hello") inside console return undefined?

Tags: javascript, console

Out of curiosity, why does writing `console.log("hello")` inside console return undefined?

Is it for the same reasons in defining void function in C?

[image]

Comment: Because `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: All JS functions have a return value. When one isn't explicitly defined, it returns `undefined` automatically. So either `console.log()` explicitly returns that value, or it gives no explicit return value and gets that as the default.

Answer (score 1):

The console.log just write a text and return with undefined.
If you create a function, add a returning value, there will be not undefined, it will returns with the added value.
Example:

```
function writer(){
    console.log("write new line");
    return "ok";
}
```

If you call the writer() that the output is "ok" in new line after "write new line".